When does bundling wire with zips become a problem?
Homeowner and new(ish) to electrical. I wasn’t aware until after I ran and hung all my wire that bundling it could be an issue. I was simply trying to be neat.
I’m this cluster, I have 2 runs of 10-3 (cooktop and oven) and 3 runs of 12-2 (fridge, DW, GFCI)
I’m actually considering adding another run of 12-2 for my hood.
All in all that would be a max of 140amps (including 20a new run for hood) running through the bundle.
I’m having a hard time finding clarity as to how to know if I absolutely have to redo all this work or what derating would be required.
Thanks for your help!
P.S. I'm in Seattle, WA if that makes any difference in your answer.




Isn't this really two questions in one—the question about bundling, and the question about zip ties fastening the bundles to the joist?

To me, that yellow cable coming out of the bottom of the double socket in the last picture looks a bit tight. Maybe it's just the angle of the photo.

Bottom line: What is typically enforced is 4 cables per bundle or through adjacent studs is the max.
Details: It looks like Seattle is NEC 2020, without 310.15(C)(1) being amended:

The ampacity of each conductor shall be reduced as shown in Table
310.15(C)(1) where the number of current-carrying conductors in a raceway or cable exceeds three, or where single conductors or
multiconductor cables not installed in raceways are installed without
maintaining spacing for a continuous length longer than 600 mm (24
in.)

Derating of NM-B cable starts at the 90°C, but is limited already to the 60°C level. So for instance #12awg, 5 cables would be 10 current carrying conductors and would require 50% derate, so 30A #12 would require 15A protection. 4 cables would be 8 current carrying conductors, 70%, 21A allowed.
I can't do the exact calculation for each hole, but inspectors generally
just look for 4 as the practical rule.

See note below Table 310.15(C)(1) for reason 12/3 only counts as 2 current carrying conductors.

In the ceiling
I believe the only problem you have is where the cable runs along the joists and is tightly bundled by the zip ties.
Where you are running joist to joist there is enough slack between the cables in the joist bays that the joist holes themselves do not trigger derates (at least in your second photo ... hopefully everywhere), and I believe that where you run along the joists, if you just replace your zip ties with multi-cable staples ....

... that creates enough spacing that you're ok there too.
In the wall
because of the insulation I think the rules are more stringent but I don't understand them well enough and couldn't make suggestions from your one and only photo but I suspect it's salvageable.

Right on. So my plan moving forward will be to replace zip ties with these cable hangers and run no more than 4 strands of Romex down one side of a joist or through a single hole. That seems like the consensus throughout all these comments and answers. Thank you!

That's good, just a little overkill.    Along the side of a joist you can run more, you just can't bunch them up tightly.  The clip pictured in this answer is approved for up to 8 12/2 cables.    "No more than 4 cables down the side of a joist", taken too literally, would make it impossible to install a breaker panel.  Also, where you're running cables long distances along joists, over beams to the other side of the house, it's good to have them in one joist bay because you then you know where they are, you know there are no cables hidden in others, making it easier to hang fixtures.

Right on. Given that two of my 5, now 6, runs are 10-3, I'm going to hand on opposite sides of the joist bay. That image seems to match the Gardner Bender MCS-100W which is only rated for 4 10-2 and 8 12-2. Not that much more work. Just need to find somewhere local that has that hanger!

Yes that is the Gardner Bender MCS.  Home Depot has 20-bags but not 100.  There's also the Arlington CS2 and these no-name metal ones.  All of these can be retrofitted.  There's loads more that are just plates with holes for new installs but you have to string the cables through them.

OMG OMG we're talking about shopping.  I hope you see this before Central Services comes to fix it.


Zip-tied cables are quite hard to disassemble when something is to be changed. Use conduits instead.
Bundling is not a problem. You need to take it in account as well as the thermal properties of the surrounding to properly choose the wire diameters.


Ad 2:
The gauge is determined by conductor resistance (material and diameter) and heat transfer from the wire outside.
The loaded wire will reach dynamic thermal equilibrium eventually, that means all heat produced by Joule`s heat (P = U * I = R * I^2) will be dissipated in the environment. The heat dissipation is dictated by heat conductivity of the material stack and temperature difference.
In other words, the better the wires insulated, the higher temperature the wire is reaching (for the same power input). Or the better the ionsulation the lower current capacity for given gauge, or the better insulation the bigger gauge needed for the same current capacity.
Ad 1:
When adjusting or replacing zip-tied cables you have to access the whole cable to untie and replace it. Wit conduit you can attach string to the old wire, pull it out and use the string to pull the new cable in. All without any need to dismantle walls and such.
Of course this works when the conduit does not have sharp corners and it smooth enough.
If you can access the wires easily (cables run under garage roof etc.) you can use multi-cable staples.
And don't forget: The worst conditions (highest estimated load, tightest packing, best insulating segment,...) dictate the gauge.

Using conduits with individual wires is correct. But using conduits with Romex (non-metallic cable) is generally not recommended except in short runs where required to provide physical damage protection.

Bundling is a serious problem if current is flowed through the wires, because current makes heat in the wires.  The section of NEC which addresses bundling is 310.15(C)(1).  Here are the consequences of coiling at the extreme. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192923/why-is-it-dangerous-use-a-coiled-extension-cord

Cables in conduit are going to be harder to adjust when needed, than bundled. Plastic conduit is likely to increase heat build up compared to loose cables in free air.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica Bundling is not a problem IF taken in account properly. I couldn't find US code but czech code provides table of amperage limits for different gauges AND different cable arrangement. For example 25mm Cu cable is recommended with ~70A limit for 3-phase cable inside insulating wall and ~140A limit for individual (25mm gap between wires) wires in air. Same wires in touch are having ~110A limit.

@MikeB Plastic conduit asks for bigger gauge (so the wire won't heat up that much). What kind of "adjustment when needed" are you talking about?

@Crowley  I'm talking about whatever change you are talking about in your answer, where you say: "Zip-tied cables are quite hard to disassemble when something is to be changed"

@MikeB then you need full access to the zip-ties. If closed in the wall (last OP's image) one needs to disassemble the wall. With the conduit you just pull it out. And keeping cable in the wall "just in case I need longer one" is not a good choice.
